# htaccess redirect problems

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.gif)|(\.jpg)|(\.png)|(\.css)|(\.js)|(\.php)|(\.swf)|(\.xpi)|(\.ico)|(\.src)$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)$
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f

RewriteRule (.*)$ view.php?picid=$1 [L]
```

Problem is that when I visit `www.example.com`, it’s sending me to `view.php`. There is an `index.php` file in my root directory. How do I get .htaccess to ignore the index file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(gif|jpg|png|css|js|php|swf|xpi|ico|src)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.+) view.php?picid=$1 [L]
```

The important changes I made:

- The regular expression in your first `RewriteCond` is faulty. The `$` anchor is only applied to the last option in the alteration.
- The second `RewriteCond` directive is useless.
- The third `RewriteCond` that’s commented out will do just what you want: Check if the requested URI path can be mapped to an existing file.
- Altered the quantifier from *zero or more* to *one or more* characters. That will exclude the empty URI path when `/` is requested.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `#` from the fourth line and remove the space between the exclamation mark (!) and the `-f`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

This line says that if the file doesn't already exist on the server, in this case, `index.php`, then continue and do the rewrite that follows.

Also check you've got both a `DirectoryIndex` as well as checking against any valid directories.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Which would leave you with this cleaner version:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*)$ view.php?picid=$1 [L]
```

This first sets up `index.php` as the default file. Then you run the Rewrite engine, and if the requested file does not already exist on the server as either a file or a directory, will pass things on to the `view.php` file and run its magic.

Comment: i changed it but no effect. I tried adding an if(isset($picid){}else{header('Location:http://website.com');} but it still shows error